# Getting a VirtualBox error as I try to run a virtual machine. Why am I getting it?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

While trying to run a virtual machine, I am getting this error :

[image]

What error is it ? And why I am getting this ?

This is the BIOS snapshot.

[image]

*Note : I am running 32 bit windows 7 OS on a 64 bit processor.(intel core  2 duo)*

Comment: Have you enabled `VT-x/AMD-V` in the settings of the virtual PC? It's under System -> "Acceleration" tab

Comment: @TheTurkey yes, it has been enabled by default

Comment: Specific hardware specifications are also required. Run the VMWare tools to determine the cause of this error. http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ== What version of VirtualBox are you using? You should also take note of the following"some HP BIOSES have a glitch, When You ENABLE VT-X/AMD-V, You DISABLE it, so do try both ways." from the FAQ on the subject.  I found all this information by doing a Google search, the BIOS glitch, is likely the problem you face and should have been researched on YOUR PART.

Comment: @Ramhound I disabled `VT-X/AMD-V` and I think it is working, because the installation is in progress

Comment: @SuhailGupta - Yes...Because your HP's BIOS is glitchy.  You might be able to update the BIOS to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: I see you have a habit of asking questions that already have answers to them.  You might be careful of that.

Answer (score 1):

This means that VirtualBox could not use the VT on your computer. If you have satified all the requirements listed in this chapter:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html

under 64-bit guests

Then something is wrong with your motherboard or BIOS.

You can check if there is an update to your BIOS and if there is one, update it to see if it will resolve the issue.

Comment: This doesn't address the author's problem his hardware supports the extensions thus does support what he wants to do.

Comment: true, but sometimes a BIOS bug would cause a problem like this in my experience. I only suggested a thing to try and did not claim that it would necessarily solve the problem. when you contact vendor, almost without failure they will ask you to make sure that you bios, firmware etc. are up to date.